# Displaying user entered text for re-editing won't pass w3c validataion

Tags: php, w3c-validation, htmlspecialchars

I am trying to wrap my head around how to have an enter/save/re-display/re-edit/save cycle and pass w3c validation for html5.

The data can have htmlspecialchars in it (e.g. links or other html code)
The data is purified with HTMLPurify() before being saved to the database.

The problem:

- If I display the data for re-editing as is, w3c will generate errors
  for '&' and other special characters entered in the text.
- If I use `htmlspecialchars()` before displaying, I can't use
  `htmlspecialchars_decode()` after editing without potentially messing
  up what was entered. For example, if I enter `&amp;` manually in the
  text while re-editing, I don't want it decoded back to `&`.

Is there any way around this? This is not an issue of security, but how to follow the rules and retain functionality.

Comment: What I do is save the "raw" text directly to the database and only use `htmlspecialchars()` when showing it to the user (or adding it as a default value to an input, for example).

Comment: After using `htmlspecialchars()` to show their user entered text to the user for reediting, when you save the data again, any changes made with `htmlspecialchars()` are still present (e.g. `&amp;`) Do you then use htmlspecialchars_decode() before saving?

Comment: Let's assume you wanna save the `<HEHE>` string to the database. You write it to an input and it is saved literally to the db. When trying to edit it, the HTML will be `<input type="text" name="the_text" value="&lt;HEHE&gt;" />`, but the user will see it as `<HEHE>` in the user interface (and will save without special characters). It works that way for me at least, just make sure to define a character encoding to your website (UTF-8).